# Why is bower recommending to ignore minified source file?

Tags: javascript, bower

According to [Bower's specification](https://github.com/bower/bower.json-spec), they said "Do not include minified files". It seems unnecessary. Why do I have to re-minify those libraries by my own?

Comment: Use unminified code since bower will compress then at the end for you during the build command

Comment: @STEEL Bower will do it? [ref](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/368) ? Seems like I have to write compress rules in my Gruntfile or gulpfile.

My point is if they already put minified version of code in their repository, preventing it downloading through bower doesn't make any sense. There is no difference between official minified version and local minified version.

Yes, I am too lazy to write compress rules for those files.

Answer (score 0):

I believe minifiers like Uglify and Closure do a bit more voodoo than just make code smaller; I believe they also try and optimize the code as well as possible.

If you include the pre-minified version, these compilers might have trouble optimizing code for this particular project.